# how do to sort a python dictionary with multiple attributes and unicode strings

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, unicode

I have a list of dictionaries with some strings containing artists and their albums (fetched from Spotify). I want to sort this dictionary by artist first and then by album. But I want to use a locale aware sort (German in my case).

I found out that I can sort a list of dictionaries with multiple key like so:

```
somelist.sort(key=lambda k: (k['artist'].lower(), k["album"].lower()))
```

`.lower` because I want a case insensitive sort.

This works fine for English named artists and albums, but not for none-English. I found also out that for locale aware sorts I can use `somelist.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)`.

What I don't understand: How can I combine locale-aware AND multiple key sorts?

Answer (score 2):

Why not compose the two?

```
def normalizeSortString(s):
    return local.strxfrm(s).lower()

def getSortKey(k):
    return (normalizeSortString(k['artist']), normalizeSortString(k["album"]))

somelist.sort(key=getSortKey)
```